# How to find joint confidence interval for a bunch of normal distributed samples

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, joint-distribution

Suppose there are two samples A and B. A has average $u_{1}$ and standard deviation $s_{1}$,  B has average $u_{2}$ and standard deviation $s_{2}$. We know they come from two independent normally distributed population. How do we find the joint confidence interval ($\alpha$) for both of the population mean?

I just don't see how the Working-Hotelling Procedure or Bonferroni Procedure apply without linear regression context.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're independent, you can just find confidence intervals for $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ separately; the only question is what coverage to use for them.

The coverage probability for the joint interval, $1 - \alpha$ will be related to the probabilities for each interval, $1-\alpha_1$ and $1-\alpha_2$, as
$$
1 - \alpha
= \Pr(\mu_1 \in I_1, \mu_2 \in I_2)
= \Pr(\mu_1 \in I_1) \Pr(\mu_2 \in I_2)
= (1-\alpha_1) (1-\alpha_2)
.$$
If we decide to use the same sub-coverage probability, $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = \alpha'$, we get
$$
(1 - \alpha')^2 = 1 - \alpha
\qquad\text{ so }\qquad
\alpha' = 1 - \sqrt{1 - \alpha}
.$$
So you can use a $1 - \sqrt{1 - \alpha}$ coverage probability for each of the sub-intervals; for example, $\alpha = .05$ would give $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 \approx 0.0253$.

(This is just the [Šidák correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0id%C3%A1k_correction). You could use [Bonferonni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction) instead if you preferred, which would give $\alpha' = \alpha / 2$.)

Comment: Thanks. But if there are many samples instead of two, would these be too conservative? Is there any less conservative coverage that I can use?

Comment: If there are $m$ samples, replacing it with $\alpha' = 1 - (1 - \alpha)^\frac1m$ would be exactly correct, in the sense that the probability that *any* of the $\mu_i$ are not contained in their respective intervals is exactly $\alpha$ (assuming the sub-intervals are exact). There are some alternatives that I don't know much about under the [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) Wikipedia article; you also might want to look into the [false discovery rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate).